# Binutils ld linker how to configure emulation mode (no supported emulations after build with mingw)

Tags: c++, linker, mingw, ld, binutils

After successfully building binutils/ld with mingw and trying to run it I am getting this message-

$ ld-new
h:/binutils-2.23.1/ld/.libs/ld-new.exe: unrecognised emulation mode:
Supported emulations:

I've looked through the internals documentation and from what I understand you need to set up the configure or makefile so that the emulation mode you want is installed during the build process but I can't work out how you actually do that.

Would appreciate it if someone could explain the process.

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that default emulation mode is determined based on target tuple that is provided to binutils `configure` script (`--target` option).

See also: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=ld/configure.tgt;hb=HEAD